# Blocking Map.get() with a Future?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, future

I have a situation where I want to wait on the `get()` method of `Map` until a particular key is available. To solve this I've been writing a Map implementation called BlockingMap which does just this.

But then I read some of the answers here on a similar question:

[Does a HashMap with a getAndWait() method exist? E.g. a BlockingConcurrentHashMap implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389122)

Is it possible to implement this with a `Map` of `Future`s? One of the answers from the other question mentioned `FutureTask` but I don't think that does what I want.

The future should contain no value until I give it one. The result is coming from a socket and I already have a thread for the `CompletableFuture`. What I'm trying to figure out is if I can block on a `Future` there while waiting for the result to come back over the network.

Can this be done with `Map.get()` and a `Future`?

Comment: I'm sure it can be - but someone needs to implement it. Standard `Map.get` doesn't support that as you can see in the API documentation.

Comment: What I'm thinking of is along the lines of `Map<?, Future<?>>.get(key).get()`. But I don't think I can simply "set" a future later.

Comment: `Map#computeIfAbsent(key, func)` perhaps? Otherwise for a `CompletableFuture` you can use `complete(V)` to provide a value.

Comment: You're right that you're going to need Futures for values. If you can use Java 8, I'd suggest making it a CompletionStage, instead, and inserting a CompletableFuture. For <8, use a FutureTask. Both those Future flavors have mechanisms for "setting them later."