# An Efficient concurrent data structure to wait for a computed value (or timeout)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm hoping some concurrency experts can advise as I'm not looking to rewrite something that likely exists.

Picture the **problem**; I have a web connection that comes calling looking for their unique computed result (with a key that they provide in order to retrieve their result) - however the result may not have been computed YET so I would like for the connection to wait (block) for UP TO *n* seconds before giving up and telling them I don't (yet) have their result (computation time to calculate value is non deterministic). something like;

```
String getValue (String key)
    {
        String value = [MISSING_PIECE_OF_PUZZLE].getValueOrTimeout(key, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        if (value == null)
            return "Not computed within 10 Seconds";
        else
            return "Value was computed and was " + value;

    }
```

and then have another thread (the computation threads)that is doing the calculations - something like ;

```
public void writeValues()
{
....
[MISSING_PIECE_OF_PUZZLE].put(key, computedValue)
}
```

In this scenario, there are a number of threads working in the **background** to compute the values that will ultimately be picked up by a web connections. The web connections have NO control or authority over what is computed and when the computations execute - as I've said - this is being done in a pool in the background but these thread can publish when the computation has completed (how they do is the gist of this question). The publish message maybe consumed or not - depending if any subscribers are interested in this computed value.

As these are web connections that will be blocking - i could potentially have 1000s of concurrent connections waiting (subscribing) for their specific computed value so such a solution needs to be very light on blocking resources. The closest i've came to is this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389122/does-a-hashmap-with-a-getandwait-method-exist-e-g-a-blockingconcurrenthashma) which I will explore further but wanted to check i'm not missing something blindly obvious before writing this myself?

[image]

Comment: have you tried Thread.sleep(1000); Just put these before the statement where you want to take pause

Comment: When a connection thread waits it ties up the network. This is not a good practice. I don't see your problem. If the result is not there, return "not complete" immediately. On the other hand your computation threads can publish a "work in progress Object" and update it periodically (if possible.) When the Object says, "almost done", then maybe the connection thread may wait a second or two.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - The question has been greatly simplified to describe the problem; real world its not waiting 10seconds & take it that the delay to respond is much less expensive than the time on connection establishment process - in this scenario 'best practice' is to wait for a short period before giving up as 95-99% of the calls will complete in this timeframe eliminating the second call.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.orTimeout​(duration)` would be a good fit. You could combine that with [Caffeine's](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) `AsyncLoadingCache` to compute and cache the work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a Future it gives an ability to compute data in a separate thread and block for the requested time period while waiting for an answer. Notice how it throws an exception if more then 3 seconds passed

```
public class MyClass {

// Simulates havy work that takes 10 seconds
private static int getValueOrTimeout() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    return 123;
}


public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
        Integer val = null;
        try {
            val = getValueOrTimeout();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }

        return val;
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);

    System.out.println("future done? " + future.isDone());

    try {
        Integer result = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.print("Value was computed and was : " + result);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        System.out.println("Not computed within 10 Seconds");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks - like your approach! unlikely to work in my scenario as the web connection threads have no control or authority over the computation of the values being picked up  - i've clarified this further

Comment: They dont need to your web connection thread will reach the [MISSING_PIECE_OF_PUZZLE].getValueOrTimeout(key, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) line which will block him for 10 seconds or less and give a result or throw an exception all you need to do is to make use of Future inside of getValueOrTimeout() method

Answer (score 1):

After looking in changes in your question I wanted to suggest a different approach using BlockingQueue in such case the producer logic completely separated from the consumer so you could do something like this

```
public class MyClass {

private static BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

private static Map<String, String> dataComputed = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void writeValues(String key) {
    Random r = new Random();
    try {
        // Simulate working for long time
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(r.nextInt(11));
        String value = "Hello there fdfsd" + Math.random();
        queue.offer(value);
        dataComputed.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String getValueOrTimeout(String key) throws InterruptedException {
    String result = dataComputed.get(key);
    if (result == null) {
        result = queue.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return result;
}


public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    String key = "TheKey";

    Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
        writeValues(key);
    });

    Thread consumer = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            String message = getValueOrTimeout(key);
            if (message == null) {
                System.out.println("No message in 10 seconds");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The message:" + message);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    consumer.start();
    producer.start();

}
```

}

With that said I have to agree with @earned that making the client thread to wait is not a good approach instead I would suggest using a WebSocket which gives you an ability to push data to the client when it is ready you can find lots of tutorials on WebSocket here is one for example [ws tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets)

Comment: Thanks for this - regarding the 'not a good approach' there is no control over pushing the client down a websocket route (many different consuming vendors - all using their own tech. stack) & the actual latency is between 200-220ms (as I said in my comment, i use 10s to illustrate the problem so i'm struggling to see how making a connection 'wait' that short period is worse than having 2 distinct calls to get the information - the cost of which is much more when you factor in the establish expense which is around 100-150ms. that said, this isn't a debate on design.